# What is /bin/true?

Tags: linux, command

On a Linux system, what is `/bin/true`?  What is it used for?

Comment: /foo/bar || true (works if /bin/true) is in the path. While not labeled as such, this question does explain something that is useful in shell scripts, makefiles, etc.. thus not voting to close.

Comment: http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/t/3779.aspx

Comment: You may want to have a look at [the source code of them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454117/why-is-bin-true-such-a-large-file-how-would-i-find-the-source-code); since I was curious.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`/bin/true` is a command that returns 0 (a truth value in the shell).

Its purpose is to use in places in a shell script where you would normally use a literal such as "true" in a programming language, but where the shell will only take a command to run.

`/bin/false` is the opposite that returns non-zero (a false value in the shell).

Answer (score 31):

From the man page:

```
true - do nothing, successfully

true returns a status 0.
```

Comment: SyaZ: You may also be amused by the description of `false(1)`: "do nothing, unsuccessfully".

Answer (score 10):

Note, it's not just silly or visually nice.  It helps for example to exit a program without activating the end handlers which might mess up when doing multi threading or forked programs.  Like in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

exec "/bin/true";

END {
  print "This wont get printed .. would have if I just 'exit' or 'die'\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen it used to fool a system operation into thinking a command has run when it hasn't.  If a command is faulty eg looping, you can replace it with a symlink to 'true' to get the master job to run. Only a good idea if the job replaced isn't essential.

Answer (score 1):

Simply saying its a program returning 0. Sometimes we need to get this value to let the script more readable. It is usually used when you need to use a command for a `true` value.

Comment: How about adding an example?

Answer (score 0):

In the UNIX shells, it's used for the same purposes as boolean constants true and false in any other language.

```
while true; do
    something
done
```

```
flag=true
...
if $flag; then
    something
done
```

Comment: how is that different from `cd .` ?

Comment: Well, for one thing, `cd .` can fail.  `mkdir foo; cd foo; rmdir ../foo; cd .`  But mostly it isn't different, nor is it different from `:`, nor any of a ton of other ways to force a command to succeed.  But it's a lot clearer than any of those.

Comment: `cd .` in a deleted directory does seem to work (with a warning message) in some shells.  But not all.