# Powershell equivalent of Linux true command

Tags: powershell, boolean, exit-code

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175405/what-is-bin-true) explains what the Linux true command is. My question, does Powershell (v5/v6) offers also a true command?

I already googled around, used `Get-help *true*`, but could not find anything about it.

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short:

- There is no PowerShell equivalent to the `true` and `false` Unix utilities.
- Because PowerShell's conditionals and error handling work very differently than in POSIX-like shells such as `bash`, there is no need for them.

The **primary use of Unix utility `true` is to reset the exit code to `0`** in situations where you deliberately want to ignore a previous command's failure (signaled via a *nonzero* exit code) in **POSIX-like shells such as `bash`**, such as in conditionals or with the abort-on-unhandled-failures option [`set -e`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) in effect.
Neither `true` nor its counterpart, `false`, produce any *output* - their sole purpose is to set an *exit code*.

**PowerShell doesn't use exit codes natively** (though you can set them for the benefit of outside callers with `exit <n>`), and **its conditionals do *not* act on them**.

- PowerShell's **automatic `$?` variable** is similar in the abstract to `$?` in POSIX-like shells, except that it reports a *Boolean*, whereas POSIX-like shells report the *exit code*; that is `$?` containing `0` in a POSIX-like shell is akin to `$?` containing `$true` in PowerShell.
- PowerShell never acts on `$?` *implicitly*, but you can use it in PowerShell conditionals *explicitly*, so that the following two - contrived for simplicity - commands would be equivalent:

  ```
  # POSIX-like shells:
  # Event though the `ls` command fails `|| true` makes the overall
  # command succeed.
  if ls /nosuchfile || true; then echo success; fi

  # PowerShell:
  # `$?` would reflect `$false` after the failed `ls` command.
  # `$null = $null` is a dummy command that resets `$?` to `$true`
  # `$?` is then *output* for the `if` to test.
  if ($(ls /nosuchfile; $null = $null; $?)) { 'success' }
  ```

While PowerShell has the **automatic `$true` and `$false` variables** (conceptually, constants), they are **Boolean *values*** used for comparison with *output* (data), **not *commands* that set *invisible status information*** (exit codes).

Read on for background information.

---

#### Conditionals in POSIX-like shells vs. in PowerShell

**In *POSIX-like shells* such as `bash`, conditionals operate on the *exit codes* of commands, i.e., (post-execution) *status information***, not their *output*.

**By contrast, *PowerShell* conditionals operate on command or expression *output*, i.e. *data***, not status information.

In short:

- Conditionals in POSIX-like shells act on *invisible exit codes* and *pass success output (stdout output) through*.
- Conditionals in PowerShell act on *success output* and *consume it* in the process.

Both shells pass *error* output (stderr) through.

---

#### If you want a PowerShell conditional to act on a command's (post-execution) *status* (success vs. failure):

You can use the **automatic `$?` variable**, whose behavior depends on whether the command at hand is a PowerShell-native one or an external program such as a Unix utility:

- **External programs:** If the program's exit code is `0`, `$?` reflects `$true`, otherwise `$false`

  - This is akin to the built-in `$?` variable in POSIX-like shells such as `bash`, except that `$?` there contains the actual *exit code*; that is, `$?` containing `0` in a POSIX-like shell is the same as `$?` containing `$true` in PowerShell after execution of an external program.

    - To get the actual exit code in PowerShell, use the **automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable**, which reflect's the exit code of the most recently executed *external program* (PowerShell-native commands generally do not set exit codes, though you can use `exit <n>` in scripts, primarily for reporting exit codes to *outside callers*).
- **PowerShell-native commands** (cmdlets, functions, scripts): `$?` is `$true` if the command did not fail fundamentally and did not write to PowerShell's error stream (such as with `Write-Error`; note that *stderr* output from external programs by default does *not* write to PowerShell's error stream).

  - Note that `$?` therefore does not necessarily tell you whether a given command considered its overall execution successful or not; `$?` being `$false` merely tells you only that *some* error was reported.
  - However, you can **wrap a command invocation in a `try { ... } catch { ... }` statement**, which helps you **distinguish *non-terminating* from *terminating* errors** (by default only the latter trigger the `catch` block);

**Use of `$?` is not common in PowerShell**, because failure is typically  handled with the 
`-ErrorAction` common parameter / `$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable and/or `try { ... } catch { ... }` statements.

That said, these methods cannot be used on ***external programs***, where **testing `$?` or `$LASTEXITCODE` is a *must*** to detect failure.
[This GitHub discussion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9140) and [this RFC draft](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/88/files) call for better integration of external programs with PowerShell's error handling.

For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's error handling, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [the `about_Automatic_Variables` topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#long-description) where the variables `$true` and `$false` are described.

I wrote this out as an answer because I wanted to point out a "gotcha" I ran into dealing with these values: `0` and `1` are equal to `$false` and `$true`, respectively.

```
$false -eq 0 # => True
$false -eq $null # => False - not false-y?

$true -eq 1 # => True
$true -eq 2 # => True - appears to be truth-y
```

Meanwhile, the string `'false'` is not.

```
$false -eq 'False' # => False
```

Also, for some reason, `$false` is equal to an empty string:

```
$false -eq '' # => True
$false -eq [string]::Empty # => True
```

While the string `'true'` IS equal to `$true` (indeed, any non-zero number, and any non-empty string is):

```
$true -eq 'True' # => True
```

---

In the exploration of writing this answer, I realized a lot of `$true` comparisons evaluate to `True`, so it's safe to assume comparisons to the bool constants are truth-y/false-y.

Here are the values that compare to `$false` (which makes the following comparisons return `$true`):

```
$false -eq ''  # Empty string
$false -eq 0   # Zero
$false -eq @() # Empty array
```

The only comparison I found that failed a test to both is `$null` (so not 100% false-y):

```
$false -eq $null # => False
$true -eq $null  # => False
```

One last example edge-case that evaluates to `$false` in some other languages is an empty `[hashtable]` (or dictionary):

```
$true -eq @{} # => True
```

---

To sum up what [@Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey) stated in the comments:

```
╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ Falsy               ║ Truthy                  ║
╠═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 0                   ║ Non-0                   ║
║ @()                 ║ @(1)                    ║
║ @(0)                ║ @(0, 1)                 ║
║ [string]::Empty     ║ Non-empty string        ║
║ $false              ║ $true                   ║
║ 0-backed enum value ║ Any non-0 enum value    ║
║ $null               ║ Any non-$null reference ║
╚═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Your equality comparisons here employ a lot of the automatic type conversions. Most notably, for `-eq` the type of the right operand is converted to the type of the left one, if possible and necessary (unless the left one is an array). So comparing to `0`, the empty string, etc. will do a type conversion to boolean and, as you'd expect, most non-null, non-zero, non-default values are actually true. Arrays are special; arrays with one element are as truthy or falsey as that element. Arrays with multiple elements are truthy, but `-eq` behaves differently as it then acts as a filter instead.

Comment: Basically: To test truthiness, use `if`, as that will behave predictably, even with arrays. Don't use `-eq`, which is not a true equivalence relation in PowerShell (as it is in many other scripting languages as well).

Comment: @Joey I wasn't aware of the type coercion in effect, but I agree with your assessment; you should not use comparisons to booleans for a logic step.  If you're working with a known bool, use it by itself: `if ($bool) {` or `if (-not $bool) {`  I believe the array comparison stuff is powershell automatically unrolling single-element arrays into a scalar for the compare.

Comment: To make it short: Falsey: `0`, empty arrays, arrays with only one element that is falsey, the empty string, `$null`, `$false`, enum values having the numeric value `0`. Truthy: Any number or enum value not equal to `0`, arrays with more than one element, arrays with only one element that is truthy, any non-empty string, any other non-`$null` reference

Comment: Coercion for single-element arrays is well-defined. Comparison with operators with the array as the _left_ operand is instead filtering the array. In this case there's no auto-unrolling. As far as I remember that only applies to pipelines.

Comment: Note however that 2 -eq $true evaluates to False.

Comment: @WalterMitty That's because `$true` gets coerced into an `[int]` which is represented as `1`.  So yes, `2 -eq 1` is False.

Comment: @mklement0 It's the only one that surprised me since `[bool]$null` is `$false`.  I need to revisit this answer to be more clear as I never really dived into this topic before; just knew how to do comparisons.

Comment: An empty hashtable is truthy, because it is considered a _single object_ (not a collection), and single objects are always truthy (leaving numbers, Booleans, and strings aside), e.g., `[bool] (new-object pscustomobject)`

Comment: The bottom half of https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375 has a comprehensive summary of implicit to-Boolean coercion (I hope); I just added the `$false -eq $null` pitfall. @Joey: good summary, but there's another edge case: `[bool] (, (, $false))` is `$true`.

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks, it's been a while that I've been looking into those things (basically back when I was a reviewer for the PowerShell Cookbook 2nd ed. and was still actively golfing). Most of TheIncorrigible's confusion stemmed from muddling boolean coercion with implicit conversion, as `-eq` does more things than `if`, and the comment just got ... longer ;-)