# the equivalent of local in powershell, test if an element is contained in an array

Tags: arrays, bash, powershell, scope, contains

i want the equivalent of this code in PowerShell

```
function containsElement () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}
```

help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a function for that in PowerShell, because it comes with [collection-containment operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#containment-operators) 
`-contains` and `-in` (they only differ by whether the array goes on the LHS or RHS):

```
# Sample value to test.
$element = 1

# Sample array to test against.
$array = 5, 3, 2, 1, 6

# Test if the value is in the array.
$contains = $element -in $array

# output the value of $contains
$contains
```

The above yields `True` (the output representation of `$true`), as expected.

**Caveat**: PowerShell, unlike traditional shells, has a *rich type system* based on .NET, which means that (implied) equality comparisons may not always work as expected; in short, due to automatic type conversions, the order of operands in a comparison matters, so that `'0xa' -in 10, 'other'` is `$true`, but `10 -in '0xa', 'other'` is not - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54490092/45375) for details.

---

If you do need to replicate your Bash function with the array elements passed as *individual arguments*:

```
function containsElement {
    # Save the 1st argument passed and the remaining ones
    # in separate local variables, using a destructuring assignment.
    # $args is an automatic variable that contains the arguments
    # passed as an array ([object[]]), akin to $@ in Bash.
    $e, $arr = $args
    # Test, and implicitly output the Boolean result.
    $e -in $arr
}

# Sample call, equivalent of above.
containsElement 1  5 3 2 1 6
```

Also note that PowerShell communicates Boolean values as *data* (implicit or explicit `[bool]` values), not via *invisible status information* (exit codes) the way POSIX-like shells such as Bash do - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55362991/45375) for more information.

---

#### Local variables in PowerShell vs. in POSIX-like shells (e.g., Bash)

`$e` and `$arr` in the function above *are* local variables, implicitly so; if you wanted to make that fact explicit, you could use `$local:e, $local:arr = $args`, but that is never necessary, because ***assigning to* a variable in PowerShell *implicitly and invariably* creates it in the local (current) scope**.

**This differs from POSIX-like shells**, where **assignment *without `local`*** either **modifies** a preexisting **variable in a *parent* scope** or, if there is none, **implicitly creates the variable in the *top-level* (script) scope**<sup>[1]</sup>:

- **As in POSIX-like shells, *descendant* scopes in PowerShell (child scopes and their children...) do *see* a local variable**.

  - Unlike POSIX-like shells (except `ksh`<sup>[1]</sup>), PowerShell also offers a way to **create a *truly local* variable**, i.e., a variable that is both visible and modifiable in the defining scope only, namely via the **`$private:` scope** modifier: `$private:var = 'truly local'`<sup>[2]</sup>.
    A variable with scope `$private` has the effective behavior of what you'd expect from a local variable in a *lexically* scoped compiled programming language such as C# (as opposed to *dynamically* scoped scripting languages).
- **Unlike in POSIX-like shells, descendant scopes cannot *modify* a caller's local variable by *unqualified assignment*** - or any ancestral scope's variables, for that matter.

  - However, **PowerShell offers *explicit* access to ancestral scopes**, namely via the **`$script:` and `$scope:` scope specifiers**, and also via the **`-Scope` parameter** of the `Get-Variable` and `Set-Variable` cmdlets.

See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347515/45375) for more information about PowerShell's scoping rules.

---

**[1] Demonstration of scoping in POSIX-like shells**

The followings script works in `bash`, `dash` and `zsh` (`bash` and `dash` are frequently used as a system's default shell, `/bin/sh`).

To make the script run in `ksh`, you'd have to replace the `local` keyword with `typeset` and define the functions with the `function` keyword (`function a { ...` instead of `a() { ...`), because `ksh` doesn't understand `local` and only creates local variable with the `function` syntax.
Unlike the other POSIX-like shells mentioned, however, `ksh` then creates a *truly local* variable not seen in descendant scopes, the same way PowerShell's `$private:` scope does; in other words: local `ksh` variables are *invariably* function-local, and descendant scopes *never* see them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a() {
  local var='1' # create local variable.
  echo "  calling scope before: [$var]"
  b # call function b
  echo "  calling scope after:  [$var]"
}

b() {
  echo "    child scope before:   [$var]" # calling scope's var. is visible
  var='1a' # modifies the *caller's* var.
  local var=2
  var='2a'  # modifies the *local* var.
  echo "    child scope after:    [$var]"
  newvar='hi' # assigning to a variable that doesn't exist in any scope
              # on the call stack creates it in the *top-level*  scope.
}

# Call function a()
a

# var. created in b() without `local` is now visible.
echo "script scope: [$newvar]"
```

This yields the following:

```
  calling scope before: [1]
    child scope before:   [1]
    child scope after:    [2a]
  calling scope after:  [1a]
script scope: [hi]
```

**[2] Demonstration of the `$private:` scope in PowerShell**

```
# & { ... } executes ... in a child scope.
# Referencing a variable by itself implicitly outputs it (implicit `echo `).
PS> $var = 'outer'; & { $private:var = 'inner'; $var; & { $var } }
inner
outer
```

That is, the private `$var` was only visible directly inside the outer `{ ... }`; the nested `{ ... }` again saw the grandparent scope's `$var`.